My local variable on C debugger shows as hex
Debugger Local Variable
I have a problem on my local variable, it's confusing for me to read it as hexadecimal. I want it to show as decimal, is there any way to fix this problem? Or gdb is the problem? I already searching around and i haven't see any way to fix this.

It looks like a GDB thing but there should be an option to switch between hex and decimal. If you right-click one of those values it should show the option.

Try to configure gdb to display values in decimal format.
Print the value of myVar in decimal
> p /d myVar

Or, change the default number format in GDB to decimal
> set output-radix 10


It helps when i add the "set output-radix 10" on setup command launch.json when debugging. So i can run it automatically every i run debug.
